# Best logging practices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging

I'm Using C# with Unity, I'm attempting to organize my debugging. The way i have it done now runs into the problem of stacking up the more "Conditional"s i add. Is there a way i don't know of where debug messages can be cleanly separated or filtered away whenever unnecessary? I don't want to keep modifying the Project Settings, or the RSP file if they grow beyond possibility of just a mess of defines.

I've looked into Script defines, but unless loaded through the player settings each file will count by itself.

This is what i ended up with to keep things sane.

```
    public class Cosmetics
    {
        [Conditional("COSMETICS_LOG")] static public void LogWarning(string message) => Debug.LogWarning(message);
        [Conditional("COSMETICS_LOG")] static public void LogError(string message) => Debug.LogError(message);
        [Conditional("COSMETICS_LOG")] static public void Log(string message) => Debug.Log(message);
    }
    public class Badge
    {
        [Conditional("BADGE_LOG")] static public void LogWarning(string message) => Debug.LogWarning(message);
        [Conditional("BADGE_LOG")] static public void LogError(string message) => Debug.LogError(message);
    }
    public class Analytics ...
}
```

I'm able to properly see them if i put them in the player settings as global defines. 
Files that have those definied in will also display them properly. 
Adding them through rsp files, works as well.